# Asp.Net Core Spa how to redirect to external url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-core

Got an Asp.Net Core 3.0 Angular Spa application. Need to call an external url to enable the user to handle payments (so not 100% spa...). How to implement this in a HttpPut request from my controller? Simplified the code looks like:

```
[HttpPut("PayOrder")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PayOrder(Order orderInfo)
{
  if (orderInfo.HasErrors())
  {
    return BadRequest();
  }

  string destinationUrl = GetExternalPaymentUrl(orderInfo);

  Response.Redirect(destinationUrl);
}
```

The Response.Redirect (or RedirectToAbsoluteUrl) doesn't work. How to show the user the external payment page (the destinationUrl)?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple solution is to return the destinationUrl from the put method and set that result as the new windows location.

```
[HttpPut("PayOrder")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PayOrder(Order orderInfo)
{
  ...
  string destinationUrl = GetExternalPaymentUrl(orderInfo);
  return new JsonResult(serviceReturn.destinationUrl);
}
```

and the client side:

```
payOrder(order: Order): {
  const options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  this.http.put<string>(`${this.baseUrl}basicpersoncompanyinfo/PayOrder`, order, options)
    .subscribe(url => {
      window.location.href = url;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using http PUT you *could* return `201` with `content-location` set to the new url as is common:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT

You can then use angular to get the `content-location` and forward to user to that page.

You should be able to return a `303` redirect for a PUT redirect though so i don't feel like this would be the best option.